# Android Navigation: How to navigate from Parent to Child to Child's Child and back like a Stack

Tags: android

I'm not sure if I am duplicating someone's question or I am just not asking the right question.

So let's say I have 3 activities that are parents of each other.

MainActivity -> SubActivity -> SubSubActvity

I know how to navigate down to the SubSubActivity but not sure how to make the back button in the action tool bar to return to the SubActivity then to MainActivty.

I've been doing this and it's crashing in the AndroidManifest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW2fl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to care about it, Android handles it.

All you have to do when you're done with the activity is to call either onBackPressed() or finish()

In your case, if you want the button from your Toolbar (if you are using [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html), if not you should be) to close and to open the parent, you should do the following :

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed(); // or finish();
    }
});
```

Then the Activity will close the parent will be displayed.